# How do I ensure correct compiler exception handling options?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've written some library code for logging out caught exceptions and converting them into HRESULTs. A colleague pointed out that doing `catch(...)` would not work as intended if compiler handling options are set-up such that this catches structured exceptions. I would like to ignore structured exceptions.

So, ideally, I would somehow like to do the equivalent of: `static_assert(CompilerCommandLineContains("/EHsc")`

My code is in a header file.

How could I achieve this or something close to it?